# Clearing RAM in batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

I've always wondered this and could never find an answer to it, but is it possible to clear your RAM from a batch file?

Comment: The only way clear RAM is to shutdown and wait for it to deay

Comment: As an unprivileged process you can't interfere with the memory owned by other processes in a modern OS. Even as a privileged process you can't completely clear it because there will be bits and pieces left in data structures internal to the Kernel that potentially still exist and clearing those out by any method other than a system power-off is both very tricky and very risky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo            ))) = Kill All Processes execpt for those needed by SYSTEM.
echo.
echo            ( process name ) = Kill only process specified.
echo  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo    Ex.
echo.
echo    iexplore.exe
echo    winchat.exe
echo.
echo.
echo    Process Name: iexplore.exe
echo    SUCCESS: The process "iexplore.exe" with a PID of 1353 was terminated.
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
pause >nul
set a=
echo.
tasklist
echo.
echo.
set /p a=Process Name:
if %a%==))) goto :ALL
taskkill /f %a%

:ALL

taskkill /f ( *.* ) & exit
```